# How do I resolve the following error in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, rxjs, angular8

> ERROR in
>   ../node_modules/@angular/http/src/backends/jsonp_backend.d.ts:1:28 -
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.
>
> 1 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
>                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ../node_modules/@angular/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.d.ts:1:28 -
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.
>
> 1 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
>                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ../node_modules/@angular/http/src/http.d.ts:1:28 - error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.
>
> 1 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
>                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ ** i ｢wdm｣: Failed to
>   compile.

I've tried all of these options and none of them worked.

```
npm install rxjs -g
npm cache clean
```

and

`npm install --save rxjs-compat`

and

`npm install -g --unsafe-perm --verbose @angular/cli`

After `ng serve --open`, the server says: Cannot Get

Comment: As a side note, be sure to read the Angular upgrade guides. rxjs-compat is no longer suggested. As well, you don't need to install rxjs globally.

If you have a modern IDE, a simpler solution to find a missing import is to delete the import line and use the auto import feature if it has it.

Answer (score 0):

The rxjs/Observable import was supposed to be deprecated in place of just 'rxjs', so you should just have to change your import from:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

to:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: in which file do i have to add this statement?

Comment: You would add it wherever you are trying to use Observables. So all of your files that have the 'rxjs/Observable' import should be changed to 'rxjs'.

Comment: I haven't used any observables so far. All I did was create a new component.

Comment: I did include FormsModule and HttpModule whilst following a tutorial. I removed them and then it compiled successfully. Did I get the error because of the inclusion?

Comment: It sounds like you're dependencies aren't all correct. In your package.json, see if your dependencies are using at least version 7 of angular forms and http:

`"@angular/forms": "~7.0.0"`,
`"@angular/http": "~7.0.0"`. 

If not, you'll want to run `npm update "@angular/forms"` and `npm update "@angular/http"`

Comment: Seems like there is no @angular/http in my dependencies. @angular/forms is of version 8.1.0 What should be done?

Comment: If you are using angular CLI, simply run `ng update`. If not, run `npm install -g @angular/cli` followed by `ng update --all` to update all dependencies to the latest version.